# HTML5 Canvas Recording Crashing onstop new Blob recordedChunks

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mediarecorder, mediastream

I am recording an HTML5 Canvas Stream using MediaRecorder. Stream to MediaRecorder is a mixed stream - it is a mixture of (1) `canvas.captureStream(30)` (2) Audio Stream (since the canvas animation has an audio on the page)

When the recording is longer than, say 1 minute, the chrome tab crashes after the line:

`var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });`

When it is less, say 10 seconds, the crash does not occur.

The resulting video is big in dimensions. Not sure if that is the issue. My canvas animation is mostly images and mp4 being played in a sequence (think of it as a slide show)

How can I fix this crash? Even when there is not a crash it takes a long time for new Blob to complete before I get the final video.